# Nagios3: File does not exist: /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/<

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

I have installed `Nagios Core 3.4.1` on `Raspbian Wheezy` using `apt-get install nagios3`. Webserver is `Apache 2.2.22`.

Installation completed without error and when I try access `/nagios3` I get prompted for username and password. Giving correct credentials leads to broken page and gives error: `Not Found - The requested URL /nagios3/< was not found on this server.`.

Similar error also gets logged to `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
File does not exist: /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/<, referer: http://192.168.1.2/nagios3/
```

Directory `/usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/` exists and contains files such as `index.php`. Directory and files and owned by `root` and are readable to `www-data`.But where does that `<` come from? I assume it is making path wrong.

Configuration in `/etc/nagios3/apache.conf` looks good to me. No extra `<` at lines such as:

```
Alias /nagios3 /usr/share/nagios3/htdocs
```

I have other web site that is configured on `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`. Configuration is simple, just document root and directory set to `/var/www`. Could it be conficting with `Nagios`?

I have tested all aliases defined in `apache.conf` of Nagios and they all work if I try access them by typing the url manually.

EDIT: <strike>I tried replacing `/usr/share/nagios3/htdocs/index.php` with custom html and php index files. My test files loaded without problem.</strike>
Turns out I checked wrong page when testing `php`, in reality it was not working and that caused the problem.

Comment: That `<` is likely due to a typo in your configuration. Have you grepped for it in all of your Apache config files, like `grep -r "<" /etc/apache2/` to look for the culprit? It sort of looks like Apache is merging one configuration directive with a second directive from the following line which starts with `<`.

Comment: Side note, quoting values in the Apache config file is a good practice and might save you from this sort of typo.

Comment: I have looked trough files in `/etc/apache2` but I was not able to find any extra or missing `<` or `>`. When reloaded Apache does not warn about any syntax errors.

Comment: You might want to check for proper EOL characters to ensure that lines are terminated correctly. It almost looks like one of the lines is corrupt, perhaps the one after `Alias /nagios3`. That extra `<` is very likely the cause of your problems.

Comment: Have you checked the settings in `/etc/nagios3/cgi.cfg` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make it as easy as possible, to track the cause.

1. Deactivate the Auth* parameters in the /etc/nagios3/apache.conf - restart Apache
2. Create a simple html file in /usr/share/nagois3/htdocs and test whether it is displayed.
3. Do the same with the index.php file

EDIT: Well, if your custom html and php files can be loaded without the error, I suppose the error is in the index.php that comes with the installation.
Could I be, since it is a PHP file, that a variable should be set in a link, but this var is empty and therefore the link isn't valid? Please check the code for vars in links.

Comment: I tried these and added results to my original post.

Comment: I don't see code with the links that mentioned.

Comment: Turns out my PHP was not working. (I first checked wrong page when testing with my simple `index.php`.) Reinstalling `php5` and re-enabling Apaches `mod_php5` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The path mentioned in the error has a '<' at the end. Looks like a typo in one of your directives.

Unless it's a typo in your post of course.